# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var Layers, a;

Layers = {};

Layers.View = function(value) {
  return function() {
    $.extend(this, $("<div></div>"));
    return this.html(value.apply(null, arguments));
  };
};

a = new Layers.View(function(a) {
  return "joke" + a;
});

a('ddd').appendTo('body');
```

It renders the first time, but code doesn't work after that.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6o93jyLh/1/

Comment: code does nothing in firefox ... not sure what idea is behind `$.extend(this, $("<div></div>"));`